# Selecting elements only if have two classes and share the same first one

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

i have these elements in the HTML I want to parse:

```
<td class="line"> GARBAGE </td>
<td class="line text"> I WANT THAT </td>
<td class="line heading"> I WANT THAT </td>
<td class="line"> GARBAGE </td>
```

How can I make a CSS selector that select elements with attributes class line and class something else (could be heading, text or anything else) BUT not attribute class line only?

I have tried:

```
 td[class=line.*]
 td.line.*
 td[class^=line.]
```

EDIT

I am using Python and BeautifulSoup:

```
url = 'http://www.somewebsite'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
DicoSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
elems = DicoSoup.select('body div#someid tr td.line')
```

I am looking into modifying the last piece, namely td.line to something like `td.line.whateverotherclass` (but not td.line alone otherwise my selector would suffice already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [@BoltClock suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106207/771848) is generally a correct way to approach the problem with CSS selectors. The only problem is that [`BeautifulSoup` supports a *limited number of CSS selectors*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). For instance, [`not()` selector is :not(.supported) at the moment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1607476).

You can workaround it with a "starts-with" selector to check if a class starts with `line` followed by a space (it is quite fragile but works on your sample data):

```
for td in soup.select("td[class^='line ']"):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True))
```

Or, you can solve it using the `find_all()` and having a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) checking the `class` attribute to have `line` and some other class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="line"> GARBAGE </td>
        <td class="line text"> I WANT THAT </td>
        <td class="line heading"> I WANT THAT </td>
        <td class="line"> GARBAGE </td>
    </tr>
</table>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag and tag.name == "td" and
                                    "class" in tag.attrs and "line" in tag["class"] and
                                    len(tag["class"]) > 1):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
I WANT THAT
I WANT THAT
```

Comment: What lambda function should I write to get child tags in the very same way as the following code line:     DicoSoup.select('body div#somed tr td')

Comment: @MthClv could you, say, locate the parent `div` first, e.g.: `div = soup.select_one("body div#somed")` and then use `div` variable instead of `soup` when searching for `td` elements using the search function? Sort of like a context-specific search.

Comment: I need to combine both the conditions on the attributes class and change the id (that I wrote some id) of the ancestor div

Comment: Excellent idea! will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can chain CSS classes for a class selector.

```css
.line {
  color: green;
}
.line.text {
  color: red;
}
.line.heading {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="line">GARBAGE</p>
<p class="line text">I WANT THAT</p>
<p class="line heading">I WANT THAT</p>
<p class="line">GARBAGE</p>
```

Comment: I think the point was to have *one* selector...not mulitple ones. I'm not sure it's possible though

Comment: Correct Paulie, I am looking for a way to wrap it up in one selector; something like 
td.line.whateverOtherClass

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentionned: I want to do it in Python using the library BeautifulSoup, I thought I was just missing a piece of syntax regarding CSS selectors and that it would applicable to all programs